# Proof completion: Exercise 24(d) Chapter 3 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

**I am trying to solve (d) below:**

> Let $X$ be a metric space.

> (a) Call two Cauchy sequences $\left\{ p_n \right\}$, $\left\{ q_n \right\}$ in $X$ *equivalent* if $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} d \left( p_n, q_n \right) = 0.$$ Prove that this is an equivalence relation.

> (b) Let $X^*$ be the set of all equivalence classes so obtained. If $P \in X^*$, $Q \in X^*$, $\left\{ p_n \right\} \in P$, $\left\{ q_n \right\} \in Q$, define $$ \Delta (P, Q) = \lim_{n \to \infty} d \left( p_n, q_n \right); $$ by Exercise 23, this limit exists. Show that the number $\Delta (P, Q)$ is unchanged if $\left\{ p_n \right\}$ and $\left\{ q_n \right\}$ are replaced by equivalent sequences, and hence that $\Delta$ is a distance function in $X^*$.

> (c) Prove that the resulting metric space $X^*$ is complete.

> (d) For each $p \in X$, there is a Cauchy sequence all of whose terms are $p$; let $P_p$ be the element of $X^*$ which contains this sequence. Prove that $$ \Delta \left( P_p, P_q \right) = d(p, q) $$ for all $p, q \in X$. In other words, the mapping $\varphi$ defined by $\varphi (p) = P_p$ is an isometry (i.e. a distance-preserving mapping) of $X$ into $X^*$.

**My attempt**: Note that for any $p, q \in X$, $\Delta \left( P_p, P_q \right) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d(p_n, q_n) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d(p, q)$. Now, how can I show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d(p, q) = d(p, q)$? Is there an alternative way to prove (d)?

Comment: If you can prove, for example, that $\lim_{n\to\infty}3=3$, then you can also prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(p,q)=d(p,q)$. In both cases, you have the limit of a constant sequence, i.e., the expression you're taking the limit of doesn't involve $n$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks, I realized what I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

Here I provide an answer to $(a)$ and $(b)$ if you do not have it already.

(a) Let us prove the transitivity property of such relation.

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space.

Let's also suppose that $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are equivalent as well as $b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$. We shall prove that $a_{n}$ and $c_{n}$ are equivalent.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists $N_{1} \geq 0$ s.t. $d_{X}(a_{n},b_{n}) \leq \varepsilon/2$ whenever $n\geq N_{1}$.

Similarly, there exists $N_{2} \geq 0$ s.t. $d_{X}(b_{n},c_{n}) \leq \varepsilon/2$ whenever $n\geq N_{2}$.

Due to the triangle inequality, if we choose $N = \max\{N_{1},N_{2}\}$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow d_{X}(a_{n},c_{n}) \leq d_{X}(a_{n},b_{n}) + d_{X}(b_{n},c_{n}) \leq \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Since $d_{X}(a_{n},a_{n}) = 0$ and $d_{X}(a_{n},b_{n}) = d_{X}(b_{n},a_{n})$, the reflexive and symmetric properties are readily proven.

(b) Let $p'_{n}\in P$ and $q'_{n}\in Q$.

On the assumption that $L = \Delta(P,Q) = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(p_{n},q_{n})$, let us consider the following relation
\begin{align*}
|d_{X}(p'_{n},q'_{n}) - L| \leq |d_{X}(p'_{n},q'_{n}) -  d_{X}(p'_{n},q_{n})| + |d_{X}(p'_{n},q_{n}) - d_{X}(p_{n},q_{n})| + |d_{X}(p_{n},q_{n}) - L| 
\end{align*}

Now we prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(p'_{n},q'_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(p'_{n},q_{n})$.

Since $q'_{n}\sim q_{n}$, we have that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(q'_{n},q_{n}) = 0$. Hence, due to the triangle inequality,
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
d_{X}(p'_{n},q'_{n}) \leq d_{X}(p'_{n},q_{n}) + d_{X}(q_{n},q'_{n})\\\\
d_{X}(p'_{n},q_{n}) \leq d_{X}(p'_{n},q'_{n}) + d_{X}(q'_{n},q_{n})
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ it results that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(p'_{n},q'_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(p'_{n},q_{n})$.

Analogous reasoning proves that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(p'_{n},q_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(p_{n},q_{n})$.

Finally, we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}|d_{X}(p'_{n},q'_{n}) - L| \leq 0 + 0 + 0 = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}d_{X}(p'_{n},q'_{n}) = L
\end{align*}
and we are done.